# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I wrote a javascript code to display the next date of a specific calendar

My Function

```
function verificaDataReferencia(mensagem)
            {   
                if(document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia1Hidden") == null || document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia2Hidden") == null || document.getElementById("ddlDataPub") == null || document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo") == null)

                var objtxtDataReferencia1Hidden = document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia1Hidden").value;

                var objtxtDataReferencia2Hidden = document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia2Hidden").value;

                > Breakpoint var objtxtDataArquivo = document.getElementById("ddlDataPub").value;

                var mensagem = document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo").value;
                if((objtxtDataReferencia1Hidden == objtxtDataArquivo) || (objtxtDataReferencia2Hidden == objtxtDataArquivo))
                {
                    var x = alert(mensagem);
                    return x;
                }
            }
```

Html

```
<asp:TextBox style="Z-INDEX: 112; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 9px; LEFT: 572px" id="txtDataReferencia1Hidden"
                                            runat="server" CssClass="inputLabel" Width="15" Height="15px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:TextBox style="Z-INDEX: 113; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 9px; LEFT: 606px" id="txtDataReferencia2Hidden"
                                            runat="server" CssClass="inputLabel" Width="14" Height="14px"></asp:TextBox>
```

the problem is that the page is running well in chrome but when i run my application in IE it throw an error

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value'
>   of undefined or null reference

please help me to overcome from this problem.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            if(! IsPostBack)
            {   
                txtNomePortugues.SetFocus();
                BO.Pasta pasta = new BO.Pasta(CodPasta);
                if (CodigoArquivo == 0 && !IsJustificativa && pasta.EnviaEmail)
                    btnGravar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "verificaDataReferencia(); confirmaEnvioEmail('" + GetString("Mensagem_Confirmacao_Alerta_Arquivos") + "');");
                else
                    btnGravar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "verificaDataReferencia();");
```

Comment: on which line it gives error ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
var mensagem = document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo").value;
var objtxtDataReferencia1Hidden = document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia1Hidden").value;
var objtxtDataReferencia2Hidden = document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia2Hidden").value;
```

Reason being `txtDataRefInfo`, `txtDataReferencia1Hidden`, `txtDataReferencia2Hidden`  is a server side control and not the client side. Try this:

```
var objtxtDataReferencia1Hidden = document.getElementById('<%=txtDataReferencia1Hidden.ClientID%>');
var objtxtDataReferencia2Hidden = document.getElementById('<%=txtDataReferencia2Hidden.ClientID%>');
var mensagem = document.getElementById('<%=txtDataRefInfo.ClientID%>');
```

Comment: But how come its working in Chrome? For Chrome parser its a Html Control?

Comment: put another part of the code above, the message should appear on the screen when the user presses "Save"

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the ClientIDMode attribute on the control to:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

This works with .Net 4.0 and upwards

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain why you need that?

Answer (score 0):

comment this line for IE it may be ok :

```
// > Breakpoint var objtxtDataArquivo = document.getElementById("ddlDataPub").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

*The problem is that txtDataReferencia1Hidden and txtDataReferencia2Hidden are the server name of controls, not the client name (look the source of page from the browser).*

**Use this:**

---

```
 var objtxtDataReferencia1Hidden = document.getElementById('<%=txtDataReferencia1Hidden.ClientID%>');


 var objtxtDataReferencia2Hidden = document.getElementById('<%=txtDataReferencia2Hidden.ClientID%>');
```

Comment: Is there a master page on client?

Answer (score 0):

there is missing an action behind this `if(document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia1Hidden") == null || document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia2Hidden") == null || document.getElementById("ddlDataPub") == null || document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo") == null)`

I would expect you write the line in this way (do not forget the negation using `!`):

`if(!document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia1Hidden") || !document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia2Hidden") || !document.getElementById("ddlDataPub") || !document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo")) return;`

Answer (score 0):

You are checking to see if the elements are null in your if statement -

```
if(document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia1Hidden") == null || document.getElementById("txtDataReferencia2Hidden") == null || document.getElementById("ddlDataPub") == null || document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo") == null)
```

But even if they are null you are trying to get the value. Ex:

```
var mensagem = document.getElementById("txtDataRefInfo").value;
```

So if "txtDataRefInfo" is null the statement will return true and try to get the value anyways. Hence the undefined or null reference.